# CPackRPM compresses Man pages and then cannot find them during packaging

Tags: cmake, rpm, manpage, cpack

While creating a RPM package containing a *man* page (which installation path matches a list of known man locations), CPack seems to compress it using GZip, but then complains that the original, uncompressed file cannot be found. How should that functionality be used then?

Consider the following *CMakeLists.txt* project:

```
install(FILES test.1 DESTINATION /usr/share/man)
install(FILES test.2 DESTINATION /usr/share/man/man1)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "CPackRPM_man_test")
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "RPM")
include(CPack)
```

When the line containing “*test.2*” is commented out, `make package` operation succeeds, — that is, simply packaging a file that is *not* destined to a true man page location does not cause any trouble. However, when the full project is processed, the following error message is output:

```
error: File not found: …/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/CPackRPM_man_test-0.1.1-Linux/usr/share/man/man1/test.2
```

Indeed, that file simply does not exist:

```
$ cd …/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/CPackRPM_man_test-0.1.1-Linux/usr/share/man
$ ls *
test.1

man1:
test.2.gz
```

Worth to note is that DEB generator does not have that issue, — simply because CPackDEB operates on original files only. While looking into *CPackRPM.cmake* module, I was able to locate the code that messes with man page files, but not the code responsible for undoing the mess-up; the former code works unconditionally, — I could not spot any variable that may tell it not to compress man pages.

The only similar discussion I could find dates back to 2014 and was resolved by updating to a more current version of CMake. Since I am also using openSUSE Linux as the original reporter did (the actual release, of course), I tried to switch from the system-provided CMake 3.3.2 to a locally built 3.7.0-rc2, but that did not change a thing. Therefore, taking into account the popularity of CMake, RPM and man, I suppose that if some bug really existed, it should have been fixed long ago, so the one to blame is me. What am I missing here?

---

**Update.** Regarding the use of wildcards that was recommended, — i. e. specifying “`test.2*`” instead of just “`test.2`”. CMake does not seem to support globbing in `install(FILES …)` form: it literally searches for *test.2** and fails before generating RPM spec file. Several kinds of pattern matching are supported through another form however:

```
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} DESTINATION /usr/share/man/man1 FILES_MATCHING PATTERN *.1*)
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} DESTINATION /usr/share/man/man2 FILES_MATCHING REGEX "^.+[.]2([.].+)?$")
```

Although that succeeds, it still does not answer the question of distributing man pages in uncompressed form. Therefore, it looks ugly and counterintuitive.

Worth to mention is how RPM spec file is generated from the originally posted CMakeLists.txt:

```
%dir "/usr/share/man"
%dir "/usr/share/man/man1"
"/usr/share/man/man1/test.2*"

%config "/usr/share/man/test.1"
%config "/usr/share/man/man1/test.2"
```

As can be clearly seen, CPackRPM indeed adds an extra wildcarded version of source file name when it belongs to a known man location; unfortunately, it still retains the original (uncompressed) file name, which leads to failure. Perhaps CMake should either warn the user of consequences or even fail early at configuration stage rather than concealing the problem for some later time.

Comment: I am not familiar with CPackRPM. But this seems as problem with their template as this is rpmbuild feature. When you in %install section do: "cp test.2 %buildroot/usr/share/man/man1" then rpmbuild do the compression on the the background. So when you put in %files section "/usr/share/man/man1/test.2" it will not work, because it does not exist. You must put there "/usr/share/man/man1/test.2*". Asterisk is there because you actually do not know if rpmbuild will use xz, gz or some other compression.

Comment: @msuchy I am not familiar with rpmbuild, but I clearly see that CPackRPM explicitly handles man page locations and mentions “.gz”, although in comments only. It may be possible that packaging an *uncompressed* man page is so uncommon that nobody tested that actually. Therefore I added a custom CMake target for converting and/or compressing man pages on-the-fly, — that is an acceptable solution for me currently, but I am still curious whether it is possible to package an uncompressed man page.

Answer (score 0):

Using a wild card after a man page entry in %files will package the file independent of compression. All I'm saying is to type

```
/usr/share/man/man1/bash.1*
```

instead of

```
/usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz
```

in the %files section of a spec file.

Comment: Aside of that your answer repeats what @msuchy said, did you ever try such a solution yourself using CMake? It is that CMake generates spec files automatically, they are not edited by hand. Of course, CMake also allows supplying your own spec file, but that quite defeats the purpose of using CMake, unless you *really* need something special in your spec that CPackRPM does not support.

Comment: The problem is that rpm recompresses files while packaging in order to control for flags used. E.g. gzip includes a time stamp that needs to be disabled in order for file digests to be generated accurately. Various distros also can change compression while packaging through configuration. packaging != building: attempting automated *.spec generation is insufficiently general without a great deal of shared complicity/complexity.